# Memory Leak with axios-module from Nuxt

Tags: memory-leaks, axios, nuxt.js

I have a memory leak using @nuxtjs/axios. I don't really know if it's my code or the plugin.
My project requires 2 axios instances to run.
One to get an "anonymous token" to be allowed to access the API.
And a second one to use that token and make my API calls.

```
const createDefaultClient = (agent, $axios, $appInsights, inject) => {
  const defaultClient = $axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    httpsAgent: agent
  })

  defaultClient.setBaseURL(
    process.server ? 'http://localhost:3000' : window.location.origin
  )

  defaultClient.onResponseError(error => {
    logError(error, $appInsights)
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })

  inject('defaultClient', defaultClient)

  return defaultClient
}

const createApiClient = (
  agent,
  $axios,
  $cookies,
  $appInsights,
  defaultClient,
  inject,
  request
) => {
  const apiClient = $axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    httpsAgent: agent
  })

  apiClient.setBaseURL(process.env.NUXT_ENV_BASE_API)
  apiClient.onRequest(config => {
    const cookieToken = $cookies.get(accessTokenCookieName)

    if (cookieToken) {
      config.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${cookieToken}`
    }

    debug(`${config.__isRetryRequest ? 'Retry' : 'Request'}: ${config.url}`)
  })

  apiClient.onResponseError(async error => {
    const originalRequest = error.config

    debug(`Error ${get(error, 'response.status')}: ${error.config.url}`)

    // if we get error 401 (token expiration) we will refresh the token and retry to access API
    if (error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      originalRequest.__isRetryRequest = true

      const refreshToken = $cookies.get(refreshTokenCookieName)

      let fetchAnonymousToken = true
      let response = null

      // if we had a cookie try to refresh it
      if (refreshToken) {
        response = await defaultClient.$post(`/forms/refresh`, {
          refreshToken
        })
        if (!response) throw new Error('Auth failure')
        if (process.client) {
          createAuthCookies($cookies, response, request)
        }
        fetchAnonymousToken = false
      }

      // else fetch an anonymous cookie
      if (fetchAnonymousToken) {
        response = await defaultClient.$get(`/forms/anonymous`)
        if (!response) throw new Error('Auth failure')
        if (process.client) {
          createAuthCookies($cookies, response, request)
        }
      }

      // resend API request with the new valid token
      originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${get(
        response,
        'access_token'
      )}`
      return apiClient(originalRequest)
    } else {
      logError(error, $appInsights)
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  })

  inject('apiClient', apiClient)
}

export default function({ $axios, app, req }, inject) {
  const { $cookies} = app

  const agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'
  })

  const defaultClient = createDefaultClient(agent, $axios, inject)

  createApiClient(
    agent,
    $axios,
    $cookies,
    defaultClient,
    inject,
    req
  )
}
```

Basically I've followed the doc here : https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend
I've commented everything in my projet and without the API calls the memory get garbage collected.

[Here the memory before the charge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a87HR.png)

[Here after the charge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9AjV.png)

After a siege, we can clearly see that the memory won't go down :/

Please help me i'm desesperate..